# How can I limit csv reads on columns that dont match?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I was wondering if there was a way to not read in a CSV if that CSV's columns do match what I am expecting. I currently am catching a parsing error on a bad CSV but there is one test file I have that is just a plain sentence that keeps getting added to my data frame. How can I stop this from happening? Below is my code that is reading URLs and passing them to pandas read_csv().

```
def read_files():
    t0 = time.process_time()
    with open('data/url') as f:
         for line in f:
             files.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

    df_list = []
    for file in files:
        try:
            df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))
        except ParserError as pe:
            logging.error(f'Parsing Error on {file}. Error: {pe}')
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
    t1 = time.process_time()
    print(f'It took {t1 - t0} seconds, to read and fill the dataframe.')
    return df


def run_calculations(df):
    average = round(df[' age'].mean())
    median = df[' age'].median()
    print(f'The Average Age: {average}, The Median Age is {median}')
    print(df[df[' age'] == median])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        executor.submit(run_calculations(read_files()))
```

edit: I am working with csvs with the columns ['fname', 'lname', 'age'] and when I try reading these files I have placed a bad CSV in there that just has the text in it that says 'this is not a csv.' and it gets appended to my data frame.

Comment: Please add the error that's thrown to your question

Comment: Sorry, there is no error thrown, currently, I am working with csvs with the columns ['fname', 'lname', 'age] and when I try reading these files I have placed a bad CSV in there that just has the text in it that says 'this is not a csv.' and it gets appended to my data frame.

Comment: That's a rather general question...depending on what form 'bad' `.csv`s could take you could: count the number of columns and not return objects a different number of colums than expected, or you could examine `df.columns` and check that against an expected list and so on. It really depends on robust you need the solution to be and what form unwanted data could take.

Comment: hmm okay I see, I want to only take in data that matches the columns I am expecting.

Comment: In that case you can do something like `if `df.columns.to_list() == [MY_KNOWN_LIST_OF_COLS]` : assign_to_some_variable_to_return; else pass`. But you should be aware that that solution will be order and case-sensitive.